# Continue iteration with changed parameters after met condition

Tags: python

I need to change parameters outside the loop and continue iteration after specific condition is met.

For example, I have list of pizzas and as list of strings. I have list of sauce packs whci should be switched after condition is met.
If there is a condition 'sauce_error' in string, I need to switch to another sauce pack from list of sauce packs and continue iteration using next sauce pack.

```
#list of sauce packs
saucePacks = ['sauce_pack1', 'sauce_pack2', 'sauce_pack3', 'sauce_pack4']
index = 0
saucePack = saucePacks[index]

#list of pizzas
pizzas = ['pizza1', 'pizza2', 'pizza3_sauce_error', 'pizza4', 'pizza5']

#iterating over strings
for pizza in pizzas:  
  if 'sauce_error' in pizza:
    index = index+1 #need to switch sauce pack if substring in string
    print(saucePack, pizza)
  else:
    print(saucePack, pizza)
```

sauce pack should be switched to the next from list when 'sauce_error' occures in 'pizza' string.

desired output:

```
sauce_pack1 pizza1
sauce_pack1 pizza2
sauce_pack2 pizza3_sauce_error
sauce_pack2 pizza4
sauce_pack2 pizza5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to update your saucePack with the new index:

```
#list of sauce packs
saucePacks = ['sauce_pack1', 'sauce_pack2', 'sauce_pack3', 'sauce_pack4']
index = 0
saucePack = saucePacks[index]

#list of pizzas
pizzas = ['pizza1', 'pizza2', 'pizza3_sauce_error', 'pizza4', 'pizza5']

#iterating over strings
for pizza in pizzas:  
    if 'sauce_error' in pizza:
        index = index+1 #need to switch sauce pack if substring in string
        saucePack = saucePacks[index]
        print(saucePack, pizza)
    else:
        print(saucePack, pizza)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tobias P.G. has the correct answer however, I made a few additions. Please use the code if it makes sense to you.

```
#list of sauce packs
saucePacks = ['sauce_pack1', 'sauce_pack2', 'sauce_pack3', 'sauce_pack4']
index = 0

#list of pizzas
pizzas = ['pizza1', 'pizza2', 'pizza3_sauce_error', 'pizza4', 'pizza5']

#iterating over strings
for pizza in pizzas:  
  if 'sauce_error' in pizza:
    index += 1 #need to switch sauce pack if substring in string
    print(saucePacks[index], pizza)
  else:
    print(saucePacks[index], pizza)
```

Comment: I don't see any addition you have made. This is more or less the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: I moved the indexing to be performed in the loop. This is a good habit because he would not have missed updating the saucePack. Additionally, I changed the way he increases the index count.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating an index and taking the new element according to it, it will be more *Pythonic* to use an [**iteraor**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```py
#list of sauce packs
saucePacks = iter(['sauce_pack1', 'sauce_pack2', 'sauce_pack3', 'sauce_pack4'])
saucePack = next(saucePacks)

#list of pizzas
pizzas = ['pizza1', 'pizza2', 'pizza3_sauce_error', 'pizza4', 'pizza5']

#iterating over strings
for pizza in pizzas:  
    if 'sauce_error' in pizza:
        saucePack = next(saucePacks)  # takes the next sauce from the list
    print(saucePack, pizza)
```

Please note that you need to be careful when the iterator is exhausted (which you also need to do with an index in case it passes the list's size...)